# Cross device iframe/widget css issues

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, css

I have  a client who i am developing a widget for who want our widget to display across devices.
I am looking for the best practice way of doing this.

At the moment what they have is a link on there site which opens our iframe as a pop up using qtip and jquery  see below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.tools-1.2.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/Reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Content/RTL.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .closeWidget
        {
            left: 420px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 316px;
        }
        .emsTitle
        {
            background-color: transparent;
        }
        #OpenOneByFour
        {
        }
        #OpenOneByFour
        {
        }
        .closeWidgetOBT
        {
            left: -46px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 209px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- This is auto centered -->
    <div id="centeredTechnology" class="centered">
        <!-- We have a shadow effect to the left of the main content box -->
        <div id="leftShadowTechnology" class="leftShadow">
        </div>
        <!-- the central content box top to bottom -->
        <div id="centerTechnology" class="center">
            <!-- The Top Green Login box -->
            <div id="loginBox">
                <div id="loginFields">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="topLineTechnology" class="topLine">
            </div>

            <div id="contentTechnology" class="content">
                <div class="fullWidth-column">
                    <h1 title="Video Production and Hosting" style="clear: both; margin-top: 40px;">
                       Widget 
                    </h1>
                    <p>
                        click <a href="#" id="OpenOneByFour">here</a> to launch widget pop up demo
                    </p>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">

            </div>
            <div id="footerMenu">

                <div>
                    <br />

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="copyright">

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- we have a right shadow effect to the right of the main content box -->
        <div id="rightShadowTechnology" class="rightShadow">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function () {         // Create the modal backdrop on document load so all modal tooltips can use it
            $('<div id="qtip-ras-blanket">').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: $(document).scrollTop(), // Use document scrollTop so it's on-screen even if the window is scrolled
                left: 0,
                height: $(document).height(), // Span the full document height...
                width: '100%', // ...and full width
                opacity: 0.7, // Make it slightly transparent
                backgroundColor: 'black',
                zIndex: 5000  // Make sure the zIndex is below 6000 to keep it below tooltips!
            }).appendTo(document.body) // Append to the document body
         .hide(); // Hide it initially
        });

        $('#OpenOneByFour').qtip({
            content: {
                title: {
                    text: '<div class="emsTitleOTB"></div>',
                    button: '<img class="closeWidgetOBT" src="http://widgeturl.com/Content/Images/close.png" alt="" />'
                },
                text: '<iframe style="background-color: transparent; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden;" width="779" height="203" scrolling="no" src="http://WidgetURL.co.uk/Widgets/OneByFour/8718114621562"></iframe><div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>'
            },
            position: {
                target: $(document.body), // Position it via the document body...


  corner: 'topMiddle' // ...at the center of the viewport
        },
        show: {
            when: 'click', // Show it on click
            solo: true // And hide all other tooltips
        },
        hide: false,
        style: {
            width: 779,
            height: 203,
            padding: '0px',
            title: { 'padding-bottom': '0', 'padding-left': '0', 'padding-top': '0', 'background-color': 'Transparent', 'width': '779', 'height': '203' },
            border: {
                width: 0,
                radius: 0,
                color: '#000000'
            }
        },
        api: {
            beforeShow: function () {
                // Fade in the modal "blanket" using the defined show speed
                $('#qtip-ras-blanket').fadeIn(this.options.show.effect.length);
            },
            beforeHide: function () {
                // Fade out the modal "blanket" using the defined hide speed
                $('#qtip-ras-blanket').fadeOut(this.options.hide.effect.length);
            }
        }
    });



    //]]>
</script>
```

So the following part of the above gets the iframe:

```
 $('#OpenOneByFour').qtip({
            content: {
                title: {
                    text: '<div class="emsTitleOTB"></div>',
                    button: '<img class="closeWidgetOBT" src="http://widgeturl.com/Content/Images/close.png" alt="" />'
                },
                text: '<iframe style="background-color: transparent; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden;" width="779" height="203" scrolling="no" src="http://WidgetURL.co.uk/Widgets/OneByFour/8718114621562"></iframe><div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>'
            },
            position: {
                target: $(document.body), // Position it via the document body...
```

When this open in a phone browser it is too small and when you enlarge it it doesn't like it  - goes off center etc...

I have been looking into different ways of displaying the widget such as using CSS3 @media - and trying to just change the css for the widget but i encounter problems as the iframe is set width/height in the jquery (what i would really like to do is on a normal desktop have it popup as is but on a smaller device - i.e a phone  when the click here link is clicked i would like it to fill the whole page)

I've tried the following:

```
@media only screen and (touch-enabled: 0) {
        .w6392597
        {
            width: 133px;
            height: 135px;
            overflow: hidden;
            float: left; 
background-color:lightblue;
        }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 650px) {

 .w6392597
        {
            width: 133px;
            height: 135px;
            overflow: hidden;
            float: left; 
background-color:orange;
        }
}
```

just to see if there are differences in the colour and on my phone it is coming out orange for my phone but not on the desktop - i have added the following

```
  <!-- Viewport is very important, since it affects results of media
       query matching. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <!-- Include device.js in each version for redirection. -->
  <script src="Scripts/device.js"></script>
```

Has anyone got any advice on the best way to put a pop up type widget on to a website that is used across devices and even though i am currently using jquery and a iframe this can be changed - any advice appreciated....

Comment: If you just want to have different css for mobile devices then use media queries. If they are not working out you can also use js to change the css or whatever you want

Comment: the @media is now working but my problem is that as the iframe is within jquery where the width and height is set - i don t think i can change the size of the widget so that it is fullscreen (for a phone) so i'm looking for a way to let that happen..?